# filter-branchを使っても、ローカルの.gitのサイズが小さくならない

Tags: git, eclipse

.gitの軽量化に関する質問です。
Eclipseのワークスペースをgit管理しています。

git管理を始めた時、.gitignoreを書き忘れていたため、「.metadata」と「.recommenders」のフォルダも管理されてしまいました。このフォルダの中身はソースコードとは直接は関係なく、自動的に生成されるファイルであり、commitするたびに大量の自動生成ファイルも変更があったとして一緒にcommitされてしまいます。
おかげで.gitフォルダのサイズが大きくなってきてしまいました。

.gitフォルダの軽量化のために、.gitignoreを作成し、以下のサイトに従って「.metadata」と「.recommenders」を管理から外し、履歴から削除しました。
https://qiita.com/kaneshin/items/0d19fc1cd86f931dc855
https://developers.eure.jp/tech/alternative-git-history/

また、上記の操作だけではローカルの.gitのサイズが減らないという事で以下のサイトにあるように、次の操作をしました。
http://easyramble.com/git-filter-branch.html
https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
```

しかし、結局.gitのサイズが小さくなりませんでした。
上記の操作後も、まだ.gitの中に「.metadata」と「.recommenders」内のファイルが残ってしまっているようです。

```
USER-MacBook-Air:workspace user$ ./git_find_big.sh
All sizes are in kB's. The pack column is the size of the object, compressed, inside the pack file.
size   pack   SHA                                       location
28036  10111  50646ee98af5fa19a4538a727261cd73304cddeb  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3352301917.index
7054   2191   630a04c4153d31b0b917a52b6eb24514dcbc0f50  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/1940685342.index
4904   828    ba10aebf34fd60bd0cf5b583a3cd7a26265bf602  .recommenders/index/http___download_eclipse_org_recommenders_models_neon_/_2.fdt
4198   865    ecd13c61f37be37a57f64452e4d89ae7fcac5e59  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/2071773772.index
4021   1243   0b4fb63b024e896069e4297d5828a4853a0e33b0  .metadata/.plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/python_v1_874innp8uovopkka84p4pwnaw/python.pydevsysteminfo
3941   1218   0b692374a3adaa49fa0744bb5ef7d12c99ed743c  .metadata/.plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/python_v1_874innp8uovopkka84p4pwnaw/python.pydevsysteminfo
3883   1198   096c00c9afb87e9fc4f8794862e668ef81acee6e  .metadata/.plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/python_v1_874innp8uovopkka84p4pwnaw/python.pydevsysteminfo
3497   1077   9781c44e0f3721f3b5299dd8a9537e733adc56f5  .metadata/.plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/python_v1_874innp8uovopkka84p4pwnaw/python.pydevsysteminfo
2878   856    5d4b2620c4d6572690ab4ce341e7d29827f3a302  .metadata/.plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/python_v1_bm109oo8jsa5gnqmc06ekl12p/python.pydevsysteminfo
2873   855    180f6531173e20a51fcc648e80ecf7133379df62  .metadata/.plugins/com.python.pydev.analysis/python_v1_bm109oo8jsa5gnqmc06ekl12p/python.pydevsysteminfo
```

どうしたら.gitのサイズを小さくすることができるでしょうか？
皆様の助言お待ちしております。よろしくお願いいたします。

追記:
git_find_big.shは以下のようなスクリプトになっています。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#set -x 

# Shows you the largest objects in your repo's pack file.
# Written for osx.
#
# @see http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/
# @author Antony Stubbs

# set the internal field spereator to line break, so that we can iterate easily over the verify-pack output
IFS=$'\n';

# list all objects including their size, sort by size, take top 10
objects=`git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head`

echo "All sizes are in kB's. The pack column is the size of the object, compressed, inside the pack file."

output="size,pack,SHA,location"
for y in $objects
do
    # extract the size in bytes
    size=$((`echo $y | cut -f 5 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the compressed size in bytes
    compressedSize=$((`echo $y | cut -f 6 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the SHA
    sha=`echo $y | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
    # find the objects location in the repository tree
    other=`git rev-list --all --objects | grep $sha`
    #lineBreak=`echo -e "\n"`
    output="${output}\n${size},${compressedSize},${other}"
done

echo -e $output | column -t -s ', '
```

さらに追記:
上記の操作を行ったのち、リモートリポジトリから改めてローカルにクローンしてみたところ、クローンしたリポジトリ内の.gitフォルダのサイズは縮小されていました。
上記の操作によってきちんと.metadataと.recommendersの削除は行われていたようです。
クローンした.gitをサイズの小さくならなかった元々の.gitと置き換えることで、とりあえず当初の目的を達成することはできました。

なぜローカルのサイズが小さくならなかったのかは未だに分かりませんが、とりあえずサイズの縮小はできたという報告をしておきます。

Comment: git＿find＿big の実装はどうなっているか、記述いただいてもよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 本文に追記しました。確認をお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考にされたサイトの記述では `git for-each-ref … | git update-ref --stdin` が一つのコマンドですが、質問に記載されたコマンドでは `update-ref --stdin` が次のコマンドになっています。質問文にコピペする際のミスでしたら、質問文の修正をお願いできますか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。コピペ時のミスです。修正しておきました。

Comment: [`git gc`のオプション](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#_options)に`--aggressive`や`--force`が存在するということは、逆にいえば通常はそうではない(つまり、`git gc --prune=now`を実行したからといって必ずしもディスク使用量削減のために必要な全処理を完遂するわけでは無い)、ということなのかな、と思いました。